# Proving that the Radon-Nikodym derivative is finite

Tags: measure-theory, radon-nikodym

Suppose $\lambda,\mu$ are $\sigma$-infinite measures on the measurable space $(X,\mathcal{X}),$ with $\lambda\ll\mu$ So, I need to prove that the Radon-Nikodym derivative $f$ can be taken to be finite-valued in $X$. This is a question on Bartle's book.

I have a few questions:

**1)** What exactly means $\sigma$-infinite measure? It is just not a $\sigma$-finite measure?

**2)** This is not what the Radon-Nikodym prove?

**3**) If 2) is incorrect, how can I prove this?

Comment: I have never heard of a $\sigma$-infinite measure.

Comment: See if this thing helps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem.See the proof section in this page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your theorem should be revised as the following:

> Suppose $\lambda, \mu$ are $\sigma$-finite measures on the measurable
>   space $(X,\mathcal{X})$, with $\lambda \ll \mu$. Show that the
>   Radon-Nikodym derivative $f$ can be taken to be finite-valued in $X$.

Note I simply changed your term of **$\sigma$-infinite** to **$\sigma$-finite**. Like @copper.hat, I have never heard of **$\sigma$-infinite**.

The theorem has some value since the Radon-Nikodym does not **directly** state the derivative can be taken to be finite-valued.

**Proof**:

Assume, on the contrary, $B\equiv f^{-1}(\{\infty\}) \subset X$ has $\mu(B) > 0$. Since $\lambda$ is $\sigma$-finite, we can find a sequence of sets $A_n$ so that $A_n \uparrow X$, and $0 < \lambda(A_n) < \infty$. It follows that $\mu(B\cap A_n) > 0$ for sufficiently large $n$. By Randon-Nikodym theorem, $\lambda(A_n) = \int_{A_n}fd\mu \ge \int_{B\cap A_n}fd\mu=\infty$. This contradicts the condition that $\lambda$ is $\sigma$-finite. Since $\mu\left(f^{-1}(\{\infty\})\right) = 0$, we can always take the Random-Nikodym derivative to be finite-valued by zeroing out those data points with infinite values.

Comment: Just to be sure, what do you call $\Omega$ is the whole set $X$, right? And the $U$ set is actually the $B$ set?

Comment: @MateusRocha, yes, corrected. Thanks for noticing.